# Finding all pairs of users that have a certain amount of common values

Tags: scala, dataframe, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I am new to spark and I am trying to find specific information about a couple of lists of data that I have converted into two separate DataFrames.

The two DataFrames are:

```
Users:                item_Details:
user_id | item_id     item_id | item_name
-----------------     ----------------------
  1     | 123           123   |  phone
  2     | 223           223   |  game
  3     | 423           423   |  foo
  2     | 1223          1223  |  bar
  1     | 3213          3213  | foobar
```

I need to find all pairs of users that have more than 50 common items and sorted on the number of items. There can be no duplicates meaning there should only be one set of userId 1 and userId 2.

The result needs to look like this:

```
user_id1 | user_id2 | count_of_items | list_of_items
-------------------------------------------------------------
    1    |     2    |       51       |  phone,foo,bar,foobar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

1. assemble `item pairs` per distinct user-pair via a self-join
2. generate `common items` from the `item pairs` using a UDF
3. filter the result dataset by the specific common item count

as shown below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val users = Seq(
  (1, 123), (1, 223), (1, 423),
  (2, 123), (2, 423), (2, 1223), (2, 3213),
  (3, 223), (3, 423), (3, 1223), (3, 3213),
  (4, 123), (4, 1223), (4, 3213)
).toDF("user_id", "item_id")

val item_details = Seq(
  (123, "phone"), (223, "game"), (423, "foo"), (1223, "bar"), (3213, "foobar")
)toDF("item_id", "item_name")

val commonItems = udf( (itemPairs: Seq[Row]) =>
  itemPairs.collect{ case Row(a: Int, b: Int) if a == b => a }
)

val commonLimit = 2  // Replace this with any specific common item count

val user_common_items =
  users.as("u1").join(users.as("u2"), $"u1.user_id" < $"u2.user_id").
  groupBy($"u1.user_id", $"u2.user_id").agg(
    collect_set(
      struct($"u1.item_id".as("ui1"), $"u2.item_id".as("ui2"))
    ).as("item_pairs")).
  withColumn("common_items", commonItems($"item_pairs")).
  drop("item_pairs").
  where(size($"common_items") > commonLimit)

user_common_items.show(false)
// +-------+-------+-----------------+
// |user_id|user_id|common_items     |
// +-------+-------+-----------------+
// |2      |3      |[423, 3213, 1223]|
// |2      |4      |[3213, 123, 1223]|
// +-------+-------+-----------------+
```

If common item names instead of item ids are wanted, you can join `item_details` in the above step to aggregate on the item names; or, you can explode the existing `common item ids` and join `item_details` along with a `collect_list` aggregation by user-pair:

```
user_common_items.
  withColumn("item_id", explode($"common_items")).
  join(item_details, Seq("item_id")).
  groupBy($"u1.user_id", $"u2.user_id").agg(collect_list($"item_name").as("common_items")).
  withColumn("item_count", size($"common_items")).
  show
// +-------+-------+--------------------+----------+
// |user_id|user_id|        common_items|item_count|
// +-------+-------+--------------------+----------+
// |      2|      3|  [foo, foobar, bar]|         3|
// |      2|      4|[foobar, phone, bar]|         3|
// +-------+-------+--------------------+----------+
```

Comment: Works great. One question though. How would I go about adding a column with the total number of common_items that the two users have along with the the other three parts of information?

Comment: @AntarianCoder, you can add a column for the `size` of the generated common-items list, as shown in the expanded answer.

Comment: I do have one question left and that is why use a left outer join instead of inner?

Comment: It was meant to cover cases in which an item id in `users` isn't in `item_details`, but since `collect_list` would automatically remove nulls, leaving little benefit for using the `left` join.  I've removed it.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, without using UDFs. Since we need the common items, the matching can be given in the joinExprs itself. Check this out

```
val users = Seq(
  (1, 123), (1, 223), (1, 423),
  (2, 123), (2, 423), (2, 1223), (2, 3213),
  (3, 223), (3, 423), (3, 1223), (3, 3213),
  (4, 123), (4, 1223), (4, 3213)
).toDF("user_id", "item_id")

val items = Seq(
  (123, "phone"), (223, "game"), (423, "foo"), (1223, "bar"), (3213, "foobar")
)toDF("item_id", "item_name")

val common_items =
  users.as("t1").join(users.as("t2"),$"t1.user_id" < $"t2.user_id" and $"t1.item_id" === $"t2.item_id" )
      .join(items.as("it"),$"t1.item_id"===$"it.item_id","inner")
      .groupBy($"t1.user_id",$"t2.user_id")
      .agg(collect_set('item_name).as("items"))
      .filter(size('items)>2) // change here for count
      .withColumn("size",size('items))

common_items.show(false)
```

**Results**

```
+-------+-------+--------------------+----+
|user_id|user_id|items               |size|
+-------+-------+--------------------+----+
|2      |3      |[bar, foo, foobar]  |3   |
|2      |4      |[bar, foobar, phone]|3   |
+-------+-------+--------------------+----+
```

Comment: Thank you! This was along the lines I started thinking and I got stuck with the agg clause and i couldn't get it just right.